# Use a generated texture for Grease Pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

so I've made a building in blender with the Grease Pencil, and I've filled up with colors the walls, now I'm trying to put a generated brick texture onto these fillups, but I cant find any way. So does anyone know if there is a way? I would prefer not to use an image texture to make it random. BTW I'm a beginner. I want to replace the brown fillups with the texture schown on the right, the corresponding node setup is on the bottom
[image: ...]

Answer (score 1):

Grease Pencil Materials don't support shader nodes (yet). [Link to the docs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/materials/grease_pencil_shader.html) .
Since you can't use nodes, you can't use procedural textures like *Bricks* or *Noise* Textures.

You can still use a texture for the stroke or the fill in the material properties.
However, the controls are limited to *Blend* between a plain color and the texture, and *Mapping* (offset, rotation and scale).

Using a raster seamless texture you can achieve this kind of result :

[image]